# Remove ASP.NET Version Information from error screen when Host is change

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

During the Pen Test, we received one vulnerability. Repro Steps was Change Host (let's say google.com) to different domain and then hit URL. Then following screen shown,

[image]

Here Version Information for dot net framework is showing. I weant through various atricals on internet and they are asking to used  in web.config

This tag is already present in web.config and when we hit url without chaning Host it is showing error.aspx page but when we change Host it is showing attached page.In attached image Version Information is mentioned and I want to get rid of that.

Also on out testing envrionment,the version information is not shown with resource not found message. Is there any way to remove version information apart from customErrors tag. Please help me out. We are using IIS 10.

Comment: What did you try with customErrors? You haven't shown that in your question.

Comment: ohh sorry I missed. So here <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">. When I try website url with out changing Host it is giving proper error.aspx page but when we changed host to something different and try to hit url then it showing above error with Dot Net Framework version.

Answer (score 1):

The tag you are already using in the web.config is probably the `<customErrors>` tag. and that's great for errors that can be caught at the .Net level.

But for errors that don't enter the .Net pipeline you will need to configure the IIS error page for the 404 error.  This can be done via the `<system.webServer><httpErrors>` section of the web.config.  For example to return the contents of my-iis-404-page.htm which you locate in the root directory of the website, you could use this:

```
<system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
          <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="my-iis-404-page.htm" responseMode="File" />
       </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

This configuration can also be done via the IIS gui.  For more information about httpErrors aspect of IIS see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Comment: Thanks, Ron, I checked that in the web.config it is already present. While investigating the issue I find that since we are changing Host header here so the request is not getting captured in IIS Server Logs.is it possible? correct me if I am worng.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. The solution I am offering does not change host headers, what it does is catch the error at the IIS level and return an error page of your choosing that is a plain html page which has nothing to do with .Net and hence can't have any Asp.Net header info since .Net has nothing to do with the page it purely an IIS response.

Comment: When we change Host in request and trigger url then it request it going to Default Website of IIS. Due to that above error page is shwoing. but I m not sure how to handle this scenario? shall I removed default website from IIS server so it will not look for requested content and will give error 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: You need to handle it with the approach I said.  Spend some time playing with IIS to learn about how to return error pages in the context of a simple web site that only has one or two.html pages and doesn't use asp.net at all.  Once you understand how to use IIS GUI or the web.config's  IIS sections to configure IIS error pages then you will also understand how to have IIS return error page for situations where asp.net requests don't reach asp.net.  For example: https://www.ntweekly.com/2017/07/14/how-to-set-a-custom-404-error-page-on-iis-10/ and the Microsoft docs I already mentioned.

Comment: I tried your solution but it was giving same error then I tired by adding  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx"> tag in web.config of default website so it now allowing custom error of my website to render if Host is change. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the X-Aspnet-Version HTTP header from each response from ASP.NET, add the following code to the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```